# Large amount image data transfer

Tags: plugins, images, uploads

i've changed my hosting provider and the old one include around 25GB image data on upload folder. is possible to move all my image data to new server easily. Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, to answer your question as it is:  It is possible.

If you're also looking to find out HOW, you would need to tell us more information about your hosting though.  Do you have ssh access, FTP acess?  Is it shared hosting or do you have full access?

If you have SSH here's what I do:

**IF you can use SCP:**

Syntax:

```
scp <source> <destination>
```

To copy a file from B to A while logged into B:

```
scp /path/to/file username@a:/path/to/destination
```

To copy a file from B to A while logged into A:

```
scp username@b:/path/to/file /path/to/destination
```

**If your OLD server is still live but scp isn't working:**

Login to that server via ssh, make a backup of the directory you want to copy.  Ie if you want to copy your www/wp-content/uploads/ directory, use these commands:

```
cd www/wp-content/

zip -r uploadsbak.zip uploads
```

now move that file to your webroot folder (www/)  either by dragging in ftp or you can just mv it.

```
mv uploadsbak.zip ../
```

now login to your new server and request the file:

```
cd /www/wp-contents

wget www.oldserveraddress.com/uploadsbak.zip
```

then the wait for the new file to transfer to the new server.

After it's done, unzip it. and then remember to delete the zip file.

Comment: Yes i have ssh and ftp and its shared

Comment: They are both shared?

Comment: yes both are shared

Comment: see update above

Comment: did this help?  Please kindly check "answered" if it did

Comment: i had finals so i could not check sorry. it worked for me ! thank you!!

Comment: No worries.  Hope finals went well.  Could you make as answered?